# CSS Border for checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, mozilla

I am applying a style for a checkbox from jQuery

```
$("#reg_checkbox").css("border","thin solid red");
```

The border works fine in IE but not in mozilla , how can I make it browser compatible ?

Comment: Styling checkboxes has been very unreliable across browsers (likewise can be said for radio buttons, selects, etc).

Comment: Ok , but the problem is i am validating user inputs and for input boxes all goes bright red this checkbox is also between texts , so i should put a map saying that look here s a checkbox check it (frustrated with this !)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Outline:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kqcx7/1/

```
$('#reg_checkbox').css('outline-color', 'red');
$('#reg_checkbox').css('outline-style', 'solid');
$('#reg_checkbox').css('outline-width', 'thin');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was having a lot of trouble as i was using border and it was not working

Answer (score 0):

First result on Google - seems like this one worked for them:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=122669